# One time bind two elements to be visible on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using an external filtering service and ngGrid to display my data.  There are some controls (text box, search buttons) that I want be hidden until the promise to fill my table data is resolved, but only on the page load.  After the page is loaded, I want the static HTML external to ngGrid to remain visible.  I currently have a flag like

```
//first line in controller
$scope.isUpdating = true;
var getData = function(){
    $scope.isUpdating =true;
    ngGridDataPromise.then(function(){//operations..})
                 .finally(function(){ $scope.isUpdating = false });
}
```

So I have a function that, as its first action is sets `isUpdating = true`, and a promise inside of that function whose finally will set isUpdating = false.  The problem I have is that as that request is happening, there's a small time window where the promise isn't resolved and the ng-show I have on my template doesn't show the controls I need.

HTML

```
<div ng-show="!isUpdating"><buttons></buttons></div>
```

How can I make the isUpdating binding only care about the initial page load, or are there some more framework type facilities that I can take advantage of for this?  Angular version - 1.2.26

EDIT: using another external dependency is not an option, I'm looking for an angular way, or a clever JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I follow what you're asking but I believe you want the controls hidden the first time getData is called until it is fully resolved but not for subsequent requests on that same session? If so, I believe this would work:

```
//first line in controller
$scope.isUpdating = true;
var firstLoad = true;
var getData = function(){
    if(firstLoad) {
        $scope.isUpdating = true;
        firstLoad = false;
    }
    ngGridDataPromise.then(function(){//operations..})
             .finally(function(){ $scope.isUpdating = false });
}
```